# Marquee speed up and slow down in intervals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `css` marquee where I need to change speed in intervals.

For example: Current speed for animation is set for 120 seconds.
What do I need is to change the animation speed like this:
First 3 seconds animation speed: 120s, after 3-8 seconds speed up to animation speed 20s, after 8 seconds stop for 2 seconds to animation speed 0, after it repeat again in the loop. The transitions should be not visible in speed change, it should be smooth.

My current demo

```css
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 120s linear infinite;
    background: red;
    color:white;
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: -150em }
    100% { text-indent: 0em }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></span></p>
```

Demo: Green marque on this video: https://youtu.be/U204bO8PXcE

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide a direct answer? I'm little bit confused of that solution as I have never met with this before. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally you question make we brain freeze when im get shower i realize do this

```
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 10s infinite;
    background: red;
    color:white;
}
    @keyframes marquee {
        0%   { text-indent: -100em }
        30%   { text-indent: -85em }
        75%   { text-indent: -50em }
        80% { text-indent: -50em }
        100% { text-indent: 0em}
    }
```

Comment: You can custom the time by caculating like 30% of 10s is 3s

Answer (score 2):

I've been experimenting a bit with your example and this came out:
https://codepen.io/spooky-rookie/pen/qBYYxVg

I have done some calculations and that's why these values may seem out of the blue.
To be more precise:

- 125em / 120s = ~1.042 em/s, so after 3 seconds text should be intended at approx. 121.875em
- 121.875em / 60s (new animation duration) = ~2.031 em/s, therefore, in JS I set `setTimeout` after 2.4 seconds to apply a new animation (keyframes defined in CSS) to last for 5 seconds, and `forwards` in there will stop it after 8 seconds (two animations instead of one because meddling with `animation-duration` while it still lasts is indeed pain, as the post from question's comment present;)

In both animations, there are `forwards` for `animation-fill-mode` to stop the animation at the very last frame.

On the `:root` selector there are variables to play around with, and I advise you to do that because those above are pretty nasty as well.

`setTimeout` in JS is set to fire after `2400`ms (blind pick) because `setTimeout` is asynchronous and doesn't fire immediately (go ahead and set 3000 to see the jump in transition).

Summing up, probably not the best solution, and values need to be quite strictly counted and set but it *somehow* gets the job done.
If you have any questions, go ahead, maybe we'll find the golden mean;)

Also, those animation times are still quite big, maybe lowering them down a bit will bring more expected results.

*EDIT*: Improved solution in the comment: https://codepen.io/spooky-rookie/pen/JjvvLmX?editors=1100

Comment: Hi Jakub, thanks for posting the answer, on codepen it just stops after a few seconds and do nothing. What am I exactly looking for is this: https://youtu.be/U204bO8PXcE - check for the green marquee

Comment: Ok, I see, I see. Right, it looks a bit different.
Gonna go play with this a bit more, maybe I'll find better solution.

Comment: Ok, so I think I've found a bit more friendly solution, without JS at all, although you would still need to play with those values to make it perfect.
Code: https://codepen.io/spooky-rookie/pen/JjvvLmX?editors=1100
Cubic-bezier to play with: https://cubic-bezier.com/#1,.01,.36,.97

Values to be considered while polishing: 
 - `animation-duration` and `animation-timing-function` (the cubic-bezier() thing) inside `animation`
 - 1st percentage inside `@keyframes` - the bigger it'll be, the longer will be the pause and the faster animation (and vice-versa)
 - amount/distance of text-shadows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create mentioned animation with bare CSS, so I will provide you CSS-only solutions. As usual, it is much easier to solve problem in animation (graphics) programming, if you understand at least basic math hidden behind it (yes, even in CSS). So let us dive in:

**1. step:**

As your animation is complex, break it up into individual phases:

1. For first 2 seconds, increase value of text-indent property with speed equal to moving distance of 150em units over 120 seconds.
2. Then for next 5 seconds, speed of animation will be increased to 150em units over 20 seconds (I assume this is a step change, correct me, if I am wrong).
3. For last 2 seconds, movement will be stopped, i.e. speed will be zero.

Now, we have one animation cycle with duration of 10s, consisting of 3 linear subparts. We can call this duration period, as you want this animation to be periodic.

**2. step:**

Convert your requirements into variables and constants:

Table of constants:

| Name | Symbol | Formula | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| distance used **only** for calculation of speeds below | d | | 0em - (-150em) | | 150em |
| 1st phase period | T1 | 3s - 0s | 3s |
| animation speed in 1st phase | v1 | d / 120s | 1.25em/s |
| text position delta after 1st phase | dx1 | T1 * v1 | 3.75em |
| 2nd phase period | T2 | 8s - 3s | 5s |
| animation speed in 2nd phase | v2 | d / 20s | 7.5em/s |
| text position delta after 2nd phase | dx2 | T2 * v2 | 37.5em |
| 3rd phase period | T3 | 10s - 8s | 2s |
| animation speed in 3rd phase | v3 | 0em / T3 | 0em/s |
| text position delta after 3rd phase | dx3 | T3 * v3 | 0em |
| cycle period | T | T1 + T2 + T3 | 10s |
| text position delta after cycle | dx | dx1 + dx2 + dx3 | 41.25em |
| initial text position | x0 | - | user-defined |
| final text position | xf | - | user-defined |
| total text position change | DX | xf - x0 | (xf - x0)em |
| animation cycles | N | | DX / dx | | (xf - x0)em / 41.25em |
| total started animation cycles | Ns | ceil(N) | N or ceil(N) |
| initial time | t0 | - | 0 |
| final time | tf | N * T | 10s * N |
| animation duration | t | tf - t0 | tf |

The only few variables we need to calculate in this animation:

- total time elapsed after n-th animation cycle: `t_n = 100 * (n * T) / t;` [in %]
- total text position change after n-th animation cycle: `x_n = n * DX + x0;` [in em]

where integer `n = 0, ..., n - 1`.

It is also required to define initial and final text positions (`x0` and `xf`) to values that will satisfy equation `N = Ns`, i.e. number of animation cycles `N` should be an integer value. Otherwise, you will lose periodicity of your animation or constantness of text movement speeds.

### Solution 1

In order to satisfy above-mentioned condition `N = Ns`, let us set `x0 = -165em` and `xf = 0em`. Unless you are willing to change time length of individual phases in animation cycle or text movement speeds in them (I have considered them constant in this example), you can fix this only by changing initial and/or final text position, as your original value `x0 = -150em` doesn't satisfy this condition. That will give us 4 full animation cycles. `N = 4` also means that one CSS animation iteration will have duration of `t = 40s`:

Now, we will need calculate our variables. Partial variable denoted as `t_m_n` is ratio of actual time elapsed in m-th cycle after n-th phase of animation (see constants T1 - T3) and total animation time, and `x_m_n` is total text position change in m-th cycle after n-th phase of animation (see constants dx1 - dx3).

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | 0% |
| t_0_1 | 7.5% |
| x_0_1 | -161.25em |
| t_0_2 | 20% |
| x_0_2 | -123.75em |
| t_0_3 = t_1 | 25% |
| x_0_3 = x_1 | -123.75em |
| t_1_1 | 32.5% |
| x_1_1 | -120em |
| t_1_2 | 45% |
| x_1_2 | -82.5em |
| t_1_3 = t_2 | 50% |
| x_1_3 = x_2 | -82.5em |
| t_2_1 | 57.5% |
| x_2_1 | -78.75em |
| t_2_2 | 70% |
| x_2_2 | -41.25em |
| t_2_3 = t_3 | 75% |
| x_2_3 = x_3 | -41.25em |
| t_3_1 | 82.5% |
| x_3_1 | -37.5em |
| t_3_2 | 95% |
| x_3_2 | 0em |
| t_3_3 = tf | 100% |
| x_3_3 = xf | 0em |

Now let's convert these calculations into CSS code:

```css
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 40s linear infinite;
    background: red;
    color:white;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%    { text-indent: -165em }
    7.5%  { text-indent: -161.25em }
    20%   { text-indent: -123.75em }
    25%   { text-indent: -123.75em }
    32.5% { text-indent: -120em }
    45%   { text-indent: -82.5em }
    50%   { text-indent: -82.5em }
    57.5% { text-indent: -78.75em }
    70%   { text-indent: -41.25em }
    75%   { text-indent: -41.25em }
    82.5% { text-indent: -37.5em }
    95%   { text-indent: 0em }
    100%  { text-indent: 0em }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></span></p>
```

I suggest you to use CSS preprocessor like SASS for generating this kind of CSS code, as it supports variables and `for` loops. Alternatively, you can use CSS custom properties (`--custom-name`) as variables and `calc()` function to simplify reusability of this code.

### Solution 2

Basic principles are same as in the first solution, but this time, we will be using non-linear approximation of your complex animation using custom `cubic-bezier` timing function. I will spare you math details this time and provide you function arguments. You can find them in provided visualisation of this approximation:

[image: timing functions]

This method will significantly reduce amount of required keyframes at the cost of adding non-linearity into speed changes. This side-effect might be desirable (smoother transitions), or not (much less time with constant speed), it's up to you. Compare them in next demo:

```css
.marquee {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 40s linear infinite;
    background: red;
    color:white;
}

.marquee-nl {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee-nl 40s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.15, 0.52, 1) infinite;
    background: red;
    color:white;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%    { text-indent: -165em }
    7.5%  { text-indent: -161.25em }
    20%   { text-indent: -123.75em }
    25%   { text-indent: -123.75em }
    32.5% { text-indent: -120em }
    45%   { text-indent: -82.5em }
    50%   { text-indent: -82.5em }
    57.5% { text-indent: -78.75em }
    70%   { text-indent: -41.25em }
    75%   { text-indent: -41.25em }
    82.5% { text-indent: -37.5em }
    95%   { text-indent: 0em }
    100%  { text-indent: 0em }
}

@keyframes marquee-nl {
    0%    { text-indent: -165em }
    25%   { text-indent: -123.75em }
    50%   { text-indent: -82.5em }
    75%   { text-indent: -41.25em }
    100%  { text-indent: 0em }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></span></p>
<p class="marquee-nl">creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits • creativity without limits<span style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></span></p>
```